# "Это был наш вопрос" или "Это было нашим вопросом"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика

Я столкнулась с трудностью, как объяснить разницу между этими предложениями. В каких случаях можно сказать и так, и так, а в каких нет? Пока думала — запуталась сама окончательно. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться: в чём разница значений и/или стиля?

Answer (score 1):

**1) Это было нашим вопросом** (нашей проблемой, которую мы должны решить).

Пример: Скорее, только скорее ― **это было нашим общим девизом.** [А. А. Бек. Талант (Жизнь Бережкова) / Части 4-6 (1940-1956)]

Не ослышались ли мы? **Это было нашим паролем.** [Андрей Вознесенский. На виртуальном ветру (1998)]

**2) Это был наш вопрос.**

Значение то же, но при этом особо подчеркнуто местоимение ***наш*** (именно наш, а не чей-то).

**3) Это был наш вопрос.**  (Мы его задали).

Answer (score 0):

Правильно поставьте вопрос в соответствии с ситуацией — и увидите, что вам больше подходит.

Что это было? или Чей это был вопрос? — Это был наш вопрос.

Чем это было? или Чьим вопросом это было? — Это было нашим вопросом.